# How to use color coding for intervals for scatter plot matrix in a python pandas code?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pandas

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,4 ), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
plt.show()
```

Is it possible to view a color coded form of the above result so that further analysis is possible, for example, for column a, values between 0-50 can be coded as red, 50-100 green and so on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

At first glance, I don't think this can be done easily.

The scatter_matrix method is a convenience method. If you dig into it, you see that it allows some parameters to be passed that can change some colors easily. For example, try this instead:

```
pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, 
c='red', hist_kwds={'color':['burlywood']})
```

[image: Changing Colors with Simple keywords]

When you look at the scatter_matrix definition (and code) in pandas.tools.plotting, normal keywords are passed to the scatter plots, and the hist_kwds argument is used to package parameters passed to the histograms.

However, I don't see a way to achieve what you want only using parameters passed to hist.

At [this link](http://everydayimlearning.blogspot.com/2014/02/plotting-colored-histogram-in-python.html) I found an example which does something like what you want, which could be easily modified to this:

```
N, bins, patches = ax.hist(values, **hist_kwds)
for bin_size, bin, patch in zip(N, bins, patches):
    if bin_size > 200:
        patch.set_facecolor("green")
        patch.set_label("max")
    elif bin_size < 50:
        patch.set_facecolor("red")
        patch.set_label("min")
```

However, the key to this is that you need to grab the patches after plotting them with ax.hist (in the first line of the code above). In the pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix method, those are not returned to you.

Depending on how formal/reusable you want your solution to be, there is a way to get what you want: Define your own custom_scatter_matrix method.

You can re-use most of the existing code, then in the middle where it says

```
if diagonal == 'hist':
```

you replace the single ax.hist() call with the 8 lines or so that I showed above (and further customize the logic/colors as you want). Now it's your own method, so if you want the ranges or colors to be dynamic instead of static, you could add your own parameters for that. You have to add a couple imports, and make explicit the namespace on a few variables, but then you'll have much more control.

Here's my 5 minute effort, to show that it works, result first and then code:

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas
import pandas.tools.plotting
from pandas.compat import range, lrange, lmap, map, zip, string_types


def main():

    df = pandas.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000,4 ), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
#     pandas.tools.plotting.scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, 
#         c='red', hist_kwds={'color':['burlywood']})
    custom_scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2, c='red')
    plt.show()


def custom_scatter_matrix(frame, alpha=0.5, figsize=None, ax=None, grid=False,
                   diagonal='hist', marker='.', density_kwds=None,
                   hist_kwds=None, range_padding=0.05, **kwds):
    """
    Draw a matrix of scatter plots.

    Parameters
    ----------
    frame : DataFrame
    alpha : float, optional
        amount of transparency applied
    figsize : (float,float), optional
        a tuple (width, height) in inches
    ax : Matplotlib axis object, optional
    grid : bool, optional
        setting this to True will show the grid
    diagonal : {'hist', 'kde'}
        pick between 'kde' and 'hist' for
        either Kernel Density Estimation or Histogram
        plot in the diagonal
    marker : str, optional
        Matplotlib marker type, default '.'
    hist_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to hist function
    density_kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to kernel density estimate plot
    range_padding : float, optional
        relative extension of axis range in x and y
        with respect to (x_max - x_min) or (y_max - y_min),
        default 0.05
    kwds : other plotting keyword arguments
        To be passed to scatter function

    Examples
    --------
    >>> df = DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), columns=['A','B','C','D'])
    >>> scatter_matrix(df, alpha=0.2)
    """
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from matplotlib.artist import setp

    df = frame._get_numeric_data()
    n = df.columns.size
    naxes = n * n
    fig, axes = pandas.tools.plotting._subplots(naxes=naxes, figsize=figsize, ax=ax,
                          squeeze=False)

    # no gaps between subplots
    fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0, hspace=0)

    mask = pandas.tools.plotting.com.notnull(df)

    marker = pandas.tools.plotting._get_marker_compat(marker)

    hist_kwds = hist_kwds or {}
    density_kwds = density_kwds or {}

    # workaround because `c='b'` is hardcoded in matplotlibs scatter method
    kwds.setdefault('c', plt.rcParams['patch.facecolor'])

    boundaries_list = []
    for a in df.columns:
        values = df[a].values[mask[a].values]
        rmin_, rmax_ = np.min(values), np.max(values)
        rdelta_ext = (rmax_ - rmin_) * range_padding / 2.
        boundaries_list.append((rmin_ - rdelta_ext, rmax_+ rdelta_ext))

    for i, a in zip(lrange(n), df.columns):
        for j, b in zip(lrange(n), df.columns):
            ax = axes[i, j]

            if i == j:
                values = df[a].values[mask[a].values]

                # Deal with the diagonal by drawing a histogram there.
                if diagonal == 'hist':
                    N, bins, patches = ax.hist(values, **hist_kwds)
                    for bin_size, bin, patch in zip(N, bins, patches):
                        if bin_size > 200:
                            patch.set_facecolor("green")
                            patch.set_label("max")
                        elif bin_size < 50:
                            patch.set_facecolor("red")
                            patch.set_label("min")

                elif diagonal in ('kde', 'density'):
                    from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde
                    y = values
                    gkde = gaussian_kde(y)
                    ind = np.linspace(y.min(), y.max(), 1000)
                    ax.plot(ind, gkde.evaluate(ind), **density_kwds)

                ax.set_xlim(boundaries_list[i])

            else:
                common = (mask[a] & mask[b]).values

                ax.scatter(df[b][common], df[a][common],
                           marker=marker, alpha=alpha, **kwds)

                ax.set_xlim(boundaries_list[j])
                ax.set_ylim(boundaries_list[i])

            ax.set_xlabel('')
            ax.set_ylabel('')

            pandas.tools.plotting._label_axis(ax, kind='x', label=b, position='bottom', rotate=True)

            pandas.tools.plotting._label_axis(ax, kind='y', label=a, position='left')

            if j!= 0:
                ax.yaxis.set_visible(False)
            if i != n-1:
                ax.xaxis.set_visible(False)

    for ax in axes.flat:
        setp(ax.get_xticklabels(), fontsize=8)
        setp(ax.get_yticklabels(), fontsize=8)

    return axes    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 6):

It's not totally clear what you're hoping to get, but I interpreted your question as "I want to color code the scatter points by the value in `a` and then see how those colors are distributed in the other variables". If this is what you want, it's easy to do with seaborn:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4 ), columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
df["a_cat"] = pd.cut(df.a, bins=np.linspace(-3.5, 3.5, 8))
g = sns.pairplot(df, hue="a_cat",
                 hue_order=df.a_cat.cat.categories,
                 palette="YlGnBu")
g.savefig("pairplot.png")
```

[image]